# Shift+Tab on Jupyter Notebook not working

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, dataset

I'm learning how to use the pandas library, and in the class videos, the instructor always uses Shift+Tab to find out which code we can specify. The problem is that every time I try to use it like in the videos (inside parentheses), it doesn't work and does nothing. According to the command guide, Shift+Tab should do it, but it doesn't work for me.

[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J99FWuzyL_MPSRX4qi9U011NlohoHkw8/view?usp=sharing)

I want to see the code options that I can use.